# Is there a licence that let people see my code but not use it?

Tags: licensing

I'm building free games in javascript, with my code is easily accessible by looking into the html of the webpage.

I really don't mind people looking at my code (for curiosity, or to learn something). But I don't want anyone to use my code to make their own games, or steal the art I've done.

With this goal in mind, what software licence should I use? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to specify any license.

By default, when you publish something, you retain all copyrights on it, unless you explicitly provide a license for reproduction, reuse etc.

If it makes you feel better you can add a "all rights reserved" statement to your source, but that isn't necessary to assert your copyright.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  Wouldn't all rights reserved also mean that he isn't granting the right to play the game?  Just curious on how that would work.